# Errorhandling in middleware does not pass error

Tags: node.js, express

Basicly I got an async function like such:

```
export default (htmlFilePath, observer, redisClient) => async (req, res, next) => {

 try {
  ...bunch of logic...
 } catch (error) {
  // if i log error here it displays correctly
  next(error)
 }

}
```

So if code comes to the catch above I can correctly use the error with stackTrace etc, but when passing it with next() to go to this express function error is lost somewhere... :

```
  .get('/*', loader(filePath, observer, redisClient))
  .use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.statusCode = 500;
    // Logger only logs: TEST
    logger.error('TEST', err, err.stack);
    res.send("Internal Server Error");
  })
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I want to make use of the error in the function above.

Comment: Do you have more than one error handler?  Meaning, more than one function with the signature `function (err, req, res, next) {}`.  What does the `loader` function look like?

Comment: loader is the first async function I wrote in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23965964/5589964), can you try this code?

```
function loader(req, filePath, observer, redisClient, next) {
try {
  ...bunch of logic...
 } catch (error) {
  // if i log error here it displays correctly
    req.error  = error;
 }
 next();
}

api.get('/*', loader(req, filePath, observer, redisClient))
  .use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Logger only logs: TEST
    var err = req.error;
    if(err){
        logger.error('TEST', err, err.stack);
        res.send("Internal Server Error");
    }else{
        //Do something here
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of `try/catch` inside of controllers, error handler middleware should handle them.

From https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#handle-exceptions-properly

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  // do some sync stuff
  queryDb()
    .then(function (data) {
      // handle data
      return makeCsv(data)
    })
    .then(function (csv) {
      // handle csv
    })
    .catch(next)
})

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // handle error
})
```

Comment: Cool, I just read that async controllers should always have try/catch. I will try your approach

Comment: I do not recommend ChuongTran solution.
When I was checking `Request` types in `express` there is not listed property like `error`.
Modifying objects, when you are not sticking to their types is not a good idea, it will create such a mess in application. Also, this `.use` is not a good solution because according to express documentation, this is not a real error handler, it may cause many unexpected things to happen.